# How to check validation of datagrid cell before change edited cell

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a problem in WPF DataGrid. I found some answers simliar to my problem but I don't understand them and they can't solve my problem. Please help.

In DataGrid on Key.Enter I move focus to next cell and edit it, and it works until an user enters bad value to the cell (for example he types char to datatime column)
I use such code:

```
private void DataGrid1_KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)<br>
{
...

if (cell.IsEditing)
{                           
  //Move focus to next cell
  uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

 ...
}
```

I want to move focus only if the value entered to the cell is validated as correct. Please explain to me how to do it. I want to write code like this:

```
...

if (cell.IsEditing)
{                           
    if (cell value is validated corectly)
        //Move focus to next cell
       uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

...
}
```